# Python - Selenium - cant webscrape specific text content from html

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

i try to webscrape this part of a html:

```html
<td class="zebraTable__td zebraTable__td--companyName"><a href="/unternehmen/8116602/schneider-electric-holding-germany-gmbh" data-gtm="companySearch__searchResult--76">
                        Schneider Electric Holding Germany GmbH
                    </a></td>
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08lYp.png)

from this Site:

https://de.statista.com/companydb/suche?idCountry=276&idBranch=0&revenueFrom=-1000000000000000000&revenueTo=1000000000000000000&employeesFrom=0&employeesTo=100000000&sortMethod=revenueDesc&p=4

with this Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/rieder/Anaconda3/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://de.statista.com/companydb/suche?idCountry=276&idBranch=0&revenueFrom=-1000000000000000000&revenueTo=1000000000000000000&employeesFrom=500&employeesTo=100000000&sortMethod=revenueDesc&p=1')

driver.find_element_by_id("cookiesNotificationConfirm").click();

company_name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zebraTable__td zebraTable__td--companyName')

print(company_name)
```

I tried it for 4 hours and cant get it. I tried it with different methods like xpath, link text etc. but all i got is a empty company Name like this "[  ]".

Does someone know how selenium can find this exact piece of text "Liebherr-Hausgeräte Ochsenhausen GmbH"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text **Schneider Electric Holding Germany GmbH** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://de.statista.com/companydb/suche?idCountry=276&idBranch=0&revenueFrom=-1000000000000000000&revenueTo=1000000000000000000&employeesFrom=0&employeesTo=100000000&sortMethod=revenueDesc&p=4')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#cookiesNotificationConfirm"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.zebraTable.zebraTable--companies tr:nth-child(2)>td.zebraTable__td.zebraTable__td--companyName>a"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://de.statista.com/companydb/suche?idCountry=276&idBranch=0&revenueFrom=-1000000000000000000&revenueTo=1000000000000000000&employeesFrom=0&employeesTo=100000000&sortMethod=revenueDesc&p=4')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='cookiesNotificationConfirm']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='zebraTable zebraTable--companies']//following::tr[2]/td[@class='zebraTable__td zebraTable__td--companyName']/a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Schneider Electric Holding Germany GmbH
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: This worked like a acharm, thanks a lot. I tried to implement this Code into my whole Code which tries to generate a list of all the Company Names for 500 or more employees, but it always takes just the first Name in the list if I repeat the command. I think its because .get_attribute() only gets one attribute and not all attributes foung in the xpath?!

Comment: @Yankzz This answer is specifically to extract the text **Schneider Electric Holding Germany GmbH**. For the list of all the Company Names we need to adjust the locators. can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Thanks, I opened a new Question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669207/python-selenium-webscrape-table-with-text-in-html-using-webdriverwait

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be found in the **source code of the page** under

`<div data-company-search><div data-var-name="companyResults" data` and it is part of the page source. So you do not need selenium in order to get it. just read the page with requests and find the data using Beautiful Soup .

Comment: you are right! but i need this part of code for a code that generates a list of all the employees name. my fault, should have explained the whole thing, sorry